# Redirect Incoming mail to another servers

Tags: linux, smtp, email-server, redirection

*I do not know what are the options are and how to google them and I am little far from the subject, so I am asking it here:*

We are a student club and we have a virtual Ubuntu server by our school, it has a limited space and we host our web page there. In the back end, we want to setup such mail server that can direct incoming mails to previously mapped addresses (such as GMail). Additionally, we want our mail to be sent from this host, by setting up SMTP. We want our mail to have `mustafa@studentclub.university.edu` and to be sent from our server to have a valid IP.

I have found information on how to redirect the incoming mail, but I could not find a hybrid solution for both. I can write them on my own, with C, Java or NodeJS however I do not want to reinvent the wheeel and probably there is a better wheel out there but I cannot find. Is there any server that can do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent MTA can handle mail forwarding and sending outgoing mail for clients. The main ones on *nix are [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) and [Exim](http://www.exim.org/). With Postfix you would use [mail forwarding domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding) to handle the first requirement, and standard [relaying](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) with user [authentication](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) to handle the second.